# Python multiple lines lineplot, unable to access correct data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have a dataset with multiple columns. From these columns, I want to access `YEAR` and `EVENT_TYPE`.

```
Year

1          1997
2          1997
3          1997
4          1997
           ...
1673110    2023
1673111    2023
1673112    2023
1673113    2023
1673114    2023
```

```
Event_type

1          Violence against civilians
2          Violence against civilians
3          Violence against civilians
4          Violence against civilians
                      ...
1673110                      Protests
1673111                      Protests
1673112                      Protests
1673113                      Protests
1673114                         Riots
```

I want to plot a line graph where x-axis has years and y-axis has number of times an event has occurred that year. Each line represents an `EVENT_TYPE`.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you reading your dataframe in your code? From your question, it looks like you have two dataframes.

Comment: i only have one dataframe those are just the columns from the dataframe. I am reading csv file into dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses a minimal set of data to show how to form the data using `groupby` and then for each type of event plot a line using matplotlib. This very basic plot could be refined to suit your needs.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

year = [1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023]

event = ['violence', 'violence', 'protests', 'riots', 'riots', 'riots', 'protests', 'violence']

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': year, 'event': event})

df2 = df.groupby(['event', 'year'])['event'].count().to_frame('count')

#plot a line for each type of event
for event, new_df in df2.groupby(level = 0):
        plt.plot(new_df.index.get_level_values('year'), new_df['count'], label = event)
    
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylim(0)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

the data after grouping becomes:

```
               count
event    year       
protests 1998      1
         2023      1
riots    1998      1
         2023      2
violence 1998      2
         2023      1
```

Comment: thank you. It worked as I wanted